# Swipe to delete iOS7 doesn't work with sliding menu

Tags: ios7, uiswipegesturerecognizer, ecslidingviewcontroller

I've found a problem with swipe to delete while using ECSlidingViewController.
Before iOS7 i use this trick:

```
#pragma mark - SwipeToDelete+SwipeMenu trick
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

But now this doesn't work.

From [official git repository](https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController?source=cc) i download example project and change settings table view controller for demonstrate issue:

```
#import "MESettingsViewController.h"
#import "MEDynamicTransition.h"
#import "UIViewController+ECSlidingViewController.h"

@interface MESettingsViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPanGestureRecognizer *dynamicTransitionPanGesture;
@end

@implementation MESettingsViewController
NSMutableArray *objects;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [objects addObject:@"the"];
    [objects addObject:@"world"];
    [objects addObject:@"is"];
    [objects addObject:@"mine"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - UIViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if ([(NSObject *)self.slidingViewController.delegate isKindOfClass:[MEDynamicTransition class]]) {
        MEDynamicTransition *dynamicTransition = (MEDynamicTransition *)self.slidingViewController.delegate;
        if (!self.dynamicTransitionPanGesture) {
            self.dynamicTransitionPanGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:dynamicTransition action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
        }

        [self.navigationController.view removeGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];
        [self.navigationController.view addGestureRecognizer:self.dynamicTransitionPanGesture];
    } else {
        [self.navigationController.view removeGestureRecognizer:self.dynamicTransitionPanGesture];
        [self.navigationController.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];
    }
}

#pragma mark - IBActions

- (IBAction)menuButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewToRightAnimated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return objects.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
}

#pragma mark - SwipeToDelete+SwipeMenu trick
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Just copy and paste this code to MESettingsViewController.m, run application, switch to Settings menu item and try swipe to delete. It doesn't work.

Please, help me fix it.

Comment: I have absolutely same issue here. Did you figure it out somehow?

Comment: No, but author close issue https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController/issues/254 I can't test it now